# Replacing button onclick content to another webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and to stack overflow, just wondering if this is the right way to replace content within button onclick to another page? As it is not working in my case. This is my code:

javascript:

```
function newpage(){
    var oldHTML = document.getElementById('cambtn').onclick;
    var newHTML = "window.location='http://curv.info";
    document.getElementById('cambtn').onclick = newHTML;
}
```

html:

```
<button name="cambtn" onclick="camera();"><img id="camicon" src="Glitcher-03.png" alt="Camera" width="120" style="position:absolute; left:50px; top:50px;"></button>
<button name="btn" onclick="newpage()"></button>
```

Comment: Maybe you should re-read the [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript) because your code does not make any sense to me. Your code is saying set `oldHTML` to the button's `onclick`, and you are also setting the button's `onclick` to the String `newHTML`. If you only want to change the url, do only this: `window.location = "http://www.example.com";`

Comment: Do you want to change the location or what. I am not clear what you want

Comment: I want to change what cambtn's original onclick function to change window location instead of executing camera()... Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

General approach:

JS:

```
function newPage(){
    document.getElementById("cambtn").onclick=function(){
      window.location.assign("http://curv.info");
    };
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="cambtn">...</button>
<button onclick="newPage();">Go</button>
```

Comment: `addEventListener` is better.

Comment: @Derek I noticed the "replace" word in OP's question, that's why I use `onclick`.

Comment: I mean the `onclick="newPage()"` part.

Answer (score 0):

While you can set an element's `onclick` as a HTML attribute using a simple string (`onclick="somecode"`), you can't do the same using JavaScript. Instead, you should create some function that do what you want, and set that function to the `onclick` property:

```
function f() { somecode }
document.getElementById("someid").onclick = f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="cambtn" onclick="camera();"><img ...></button>
<button id="btn">Button</button>

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("cambtn").onclick = function(){
        location.href = "http://curv.info";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If iframe is an option you can do something like below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
    #page{width:600px;height:400px;margin:0 auto;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function oldhtml() { 
        document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = "<iframe src'http://www.google.com'></iframe>"  //loads html from another page

        }
   function newhtml() {
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = "<div style='width:100px;height:100px;background:black;color:#fff;'>NEW HTML</div>";  //loads static html 
   }
   </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
    <button id="old" onclick="oldhtml()">Old HTML</button><br><br>
    <button id="new" onclick="newhtml()">NEW HTML</button>
    <div id="page"></div>
</html>
```